# Traverse through a wxListBox in Python

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython, traversal

I have this static method that reverses the characters in a string:

```
 @staticmethod
 def reverse(s):
    txt = ''
    for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
        txt += s[i]
    return txt
```

I have a wxListBox filled with different strings. I need to traverse through the wxListBox and apply my reverse method to each string:

```
 for name in [self.listBox1.GetString(i) for i in range(self.listBox1.GetCount())]:
        self.reverse(str(name))
```

The above code is not reversing my string, but I am sure my reverse method works. How do I apply my reverse method to each string within the wxListBox?

Comment: `reverse([self.listBox1.GetString(i) for i in range(self.listBox1.GetCount())])`

Comment: I am getting a name error: Global name 'reverse' is not defined?

Comment: Replace `reverse` with `YourClassName.reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly :-) It does reverse the strings. But that's it. If you
want to see the reversed strings back in the listbox, you have to update the listbox.
It all goes around the fact that strings are immutable, and that in your reverse you
actually return a new string (reversed) but there is no commands to put the string
back into the listbox. So, something like this should work:

```
for i in range(self.listBox1.GetCount()):
    self.listBox.SetString(i, self.reverse(self.listBox1.GetString(i)))
```